# Can I perform bitwise operations on byte[]?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

Let's say I have:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 212, 29, 144 };
```

The only way I'm able to figure out to do a bitwise AND & is by first converting the byte[] to a uint:

```
if ((BitConverter.ToUInt32(data,0)) & 0x7) == 1)
{
    //If the last 3 bits are ...111, then do something
}
```

This seems ugly.  Is there a better way to perform bitwise operations on a byte[] without having to convert to a UInt?  Thanks.

Comment: `data[0] & 0x7` doesn't work ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut data[3] would work since I'm wanting to compare the last 3 bits in this example.  However, I'm looking for a solution where I can perform an AND operation on a multi-byte value.

As another example, I would like to be able to do something like:

if (data & 0x80000000) 
{
  //Do something true
}

Comment: Unfortunately, programs are only able to compare things that are the same. Either you convert data into `UInt32`, either you convert the comparer (`0x80000000`) into a bit array and do the compare for each item...

Comment: What results are you expecting when you logically AND (`&`) an array of 13 bytes with a number? Or you are expecting to have an in-built way specifically for byte array of size 4?

Comment: What would you expect the result of `data & 0x80000000` to mean? What would you expect the result type to be? It's an operation that makes no sense, IMO.

Comment: It is easy to write a method `static byte[] EntrywiseAnd(byte[] a, byte[] b)` if that is what you mean. Just return `a.Zip(b, (x, y) => (byte)(x & y)).ToArray()` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there no direct support in .Net for bit operations on byte arrays.

You can

- convert to existing types like you show in the question
- implement operations on arrays yourself and use arrays
- consider if [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) works for your cases (supports all bitwise operation on arbitrary long numbers, but there sitll no direct way to write long constanst outside regular `long` values)
- consider if [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) works for your case (better if you just need to check/set particular bits).

Comment: Another way is to use BitArray class

Comment: You forgot the unsafe solution.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution:

```
byte b1 = 0x11;
byte b2 = 0xF0;
byte b3 = (byte)(b1 & b2);
```