# Masking a byte array in C#

Tags: c#

I need to mask a byte array in C#, so I can compare it.
I have a known byte array (TDO) where some of the bits are cares, and some of them are don't cares. Which bits are cares and don't cares are describes by a masking byte array. The 1's are cares, and the 0's are don't cares.

Now I have to mask TDO with concerns to the mask array, so I can compare the TDO with another byte array. Can someone help me get started with this?

I've searched for an example of something similar, but haven't found anything.

EDIT: 
I would like to do something like this - but I don't know how to get started..

```
byte[] tdo = new byte[] {28, 82} //1C 52 in hex
byte[] mask = new byte[] {255, 3} //FF 03 in hex 

bit[] tdo_bit = ByteToBit(tdo) = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
bit[] mask_bit = ByteToBit(mask) = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

bit[] legal_tdo = bit[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

MaskCompare(tdo_bit, mask_bit, legal_tdo)
{
  //compares tdo_bit with legal_tdo, but the bits where mask_bit is 0 doesn't 
  //make tdo_bit != legal_tdo
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written trying to solve this problem and explain what is not working

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `for` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042496/can-i-perform-bitwise-operations-on-byte

Comment: Searching for [`[c#] bit mask` on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+bit+mask) yields 872 results as of this writing. Please look through those and see if any answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not need to convert it to an array of bits. You can mask the two byte arrays using the bitwise and operator as follows:

```
bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b, byte[] mask)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i ++)
    {
        if ((a[i] & mask[i]) != (b[i] & mask[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought long and hard about this.

The solution involves basic boolean theory. I will use `|` as "OR", `&` as "AND", same syntax as what C# uses.

**OR** : If any of the inputs is 1, returns 1, otherwise returns 0.
**AND**: If all of the inputs is 1, returns 1, otherwise returns 0.

Using only OR and AND, there are 4 possible operations on a binary number.

1. `x | 1 => 1` ( Always return 1)
   eg. `0 | 1 => 1`, `1 | 1 => 1`.
2. `x | 0 => x` ( Identity because it returns itself)
   eg. `0 | 0 => 0`, `1 | 0 => 1`.
3. `x & 1 => 1` ( Identity because it returns itself)
   eg. `0 & 1 => 0`, `1 & 1 => 1`.
4. `x & 0 => y'` ( Returns opposite of input)
   eg. `0 & 0 => 1`, `1 & 0 => 0`

Note: What works for individual bits works for entire bytes, so I'm going to use bits for examples.

Lets assume a = 0, b = 1. We can use rule 1 and 2 for this.

```
ma = a | m.
mb = b | m.
same = ma & mb.
```

Let's analyze the code. If m is 1, the result is always 1. if m is 0, it checks if a and b is the same.

Note to OP:
With this solution, the mask needs to be 1 to NOT CARE, and 0 to CARE. However, OP wanted to use 1 to CARE, and 0 to NOT CARE. The solution is simple. All we need to do is "negate" or "inverse" the mask. We can do it using rule 4. `inversed_m = m & 0` and use inverse_m instead of m for the rest of the code.

If you can do this for a byte, you can do the same for the entire list/array of bytes using a for loop. Here is working code.

```
bool AreEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b, byte[] mask)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i ++)
    {
        var byteA = a[i];
        var byteB = b[i];
        var byteMask = mask[i];

        // If mask value 0 is "check" and 1 is "don't check", do nothing. 
        // Otherwise (if you are like OP), uncomment next line
        // byteMask = byteMask & 0;  // "negate" / "inverse" byteMask

        var maskedByteA = byteA | byteMask;
        var maskedByteB = byteB | byteMask;

        var same = maskedByteA & maskedByteB;

        if (!same)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Warning: The accepted answer seems to be wrong.